# Directory creation not working, basic-ftp module in Node Js

Tags: node.js, ftp

I am trying to upload file to FTP server, but I see few entries but rest are skipped, even no error is generating. I don't know where exactly I am getting wrong.is it a synchronization issue or an issue from the package itself? I even used jsFtp package which can also put a buffer in the server but not works as expected.  below are my code and output.

```js
const unzipper = require("unzipper");
const ftp = require("basic-ftp");

const client = new ftp.Client();
await client.access({...options});


const zip = fs.createReadStream(path.join(filePath, `code.zip`)).pipe(unzipper.Parse({ raw: true, forceStream: true}));

for await (const entry of zip) {
    await client.cd("/");
    const type = entry.type; // 'Directory' or 'File'
    const size = entry.vars.uncompressedSize; // There is also compressedSize;
    
    let fileArray = entry.path.split("/");

    if(size > 0 ) {
        let fileName = fileArray.pop();
        let dir = fileArray.splice(1).join("/");
        await client.uploadFrom(entry, dir + "/" + fileName);
    }

    if(type === 'Directory') {
        let dir = fileArray.splice(1).join("/");
        await client.ensureDir(`${dir}`);
        // await client.clearWorkingDir();
    }
}

console.log("Entry Read Finished");
```

```js
.gitignore                             
LICENSE                                
README.md                              
app/                                   
app/bootstrap.php                      
app/config.php                         
composer.json                          
console.php                            
src/                                   
src/SuperBlog/                         
src/SuperBlog/Command/                 
src/SuperBlog/Command/ArticleDetailComm
src/SuperBlog/Controller/              
src/SuperBlog/Controller/ArticleControl
src/SuperBlog/Controller/HomeController
src/SuperBlog/Model/                   
src/SuperBlog/Model/Article.php        
src/SuperBlog/Model/ArticleRepository.p
src/SuperBlog/Persistence/             
src/SuperBlog/Persistence/InMemoryArtic
src/SuperBlog/Views/                   
src/SuperBlog/Views/article.twig       
src/SuperBlog/Views/home.twig          
src/SuperBlog/Views/layout.twig        
web/                                   
web/.htaccess                          
web/index.php
```

```
Creating Directory /
Uploading .gitignore
File:  '' '.gitignore'
Uploading LICENSE
File:  '' 'LICENSE'
Uploading README.md
File:  '' 'README.md'
Creating Directory /app/
Uploading bootstrap.php
File:  'app' 'bootstrap.php'
Uploading config.php
File:  'app' 'config.php'
Entry Read Finished
```

can any one suggest what wrong with the code. Zip is perfectly fine no error with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this using [basic-ftp's](https://www.npmjs.com/package/basic-ftp#client-api) support for `uploadFromDir` which will automatically create the required folder structure and upload the file contents. Here's a working example (tested successfully with the public ftp-server https://dlptest.com/ftp-test/):

```
const unzipper = require("unzipper");
const ftp = require("basic-ftp");
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

(async () => {
    try {
        await fs.createReadStream(path.resolve('./testzip.zip'))
            .pipe(unzipper.Extract({path: './tmp-extract'}))
            .promise();

        const client = new ftp.Client();
        await client.access({
            host: "<host>",
            user: "<user>",
            password: "<password>",
        });

        await client.uploadFromDir("./tmp-extract");
        console.log("upload successful");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

})();
```

Comment: I actually not want to extract the zip. if in case I don't have any other solution then need to think of this method. although thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: May I ask why? You can always remove the temporary file after the ftp-upload. If your concerned about the additional file-system write/reads, then this is of course not the best solution. But given the simplicity of this, I'd just go with this :)

Comment: Yes. Because normally in zipping there is an extra directory exist and in my case to know the directory name an API call will be involved even this directory will not be in the FTP server. For there reason I want, data to be stream directly and if I could manage this, in the large file I can get rid off the read-write overhead in the system.

Comment: I understand, let's see maybe someone else knows a way to do it. I'll leave the answer though :)